# Mockito: mocking class always calls real method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I would like to mock a class.

The class is called like this:

here's my code:

```
@Mock
SomeClass someClass;

@InjectMocks
ToBeTested toBeTested;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

// in the test:
doReturn(returnValue).when(someClass).doSomething(param1, param2);
```

I feel like I have tried every possible combination of `@Mock` and `@Spy` and `doReturn` and `when`, but instead of mocking the method call, the real method is called and an NPE is thrown.

How do I do this correctly?

I'll provide more code if needed.

**EDIT**

both `SomeClass` and `doSomething()` are public and neither are final.

I tried using `MockitoJunitRunnerclass` instead of `MockitoAnnotations`and the exception is still thrown.

The class to be tested:

```
@Component
public class ToBeTested implements Something {

    @Override
    public ReturnValue doSomeAction(Parameter theParam) {
        try {
            SomeClass theClass = new SomeClass();
            MyReturnValue myReturnValue = theClass.doSomething(
                    parameterOfTypeInputStream,
                    parameterOfTypeString
            );

        // other stuff

            return theParam;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Oh no!");
        }
    }

// more
```

`param1` and `param2` are of type InputStream and String respectively.

Comment: The code for ToBeTested and details about param1 and param2 would be good

Comment: Is `SomeClass` final perhaps? Or `doSomething`?  Depending on which version of Mockito you have, it may not be possible to stub final methods, or methods in final classes.

Comment: Are you using mockito junit runner annotation for the test class?

Comment: How have you tried `when`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's not mocked, the actual code create the real class in the method `doSomeAction`, in order to have the mock injected `SomeClass theClass` should be a field.

```
@Component
public class ToBeTested implements Something {
    SomeClass theClass;

    @Autowired
    public ToBeTested(SomeClass theClass) {
        this.theClass = theClass;
    }    

    @Override
    public ReturnValue doSomeAction(Parameter theParam) {
        try {
            MyReturnValue myReturnValue = theClass.doSomething(
                    parameterOfTypeInputStream,
                    parameterOfTypeString
            );

        // other stuff

            return theParam;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Oh no!");
        }
    }
```

You application container (Spring) should create the bean `SomeClass` and inject it as this constructor is annotated by `@Autowired`.

And since Mockito's `@InjectMocks` annotation will look up constructors, it will find this constructor and inject the mock you declared in your test class (`@Mock SomeClass someClass;`).

Comment: Well, the thing is, the code was written by someone else and SomeClass is not managed by Spring (it has not @Component annotation or anything).  Is it really completely impossible here to mock SomeClass? Shouldn't Mockito notice that only one of the mocks is declared as a construcor parameter?

Comment: Spring configuration can still create `SomeClass` in some method annotated by `@Bean`. Although verify that it can be shared e.g. it is thread safe. Mockito will only inject declared mocks in your test, so your test can manipulate the mock instances.